# NumPy slice notation in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, dictionary, slice

I wonder if it is possible to store numpy slice notation in a python dictionary.  Something like:

```
lookup = {0:[:540],
          30:[540:1080],
          60:[1080:]}
```

It is possible to use native python slice syntax, e.g. `slice(0,10,2)`, but I have not been able to store more complex slices.  For example, something that is multidimensional `[:,:2,:, :540]`.

My current work around is to store the values as tuples and then unpack these into the necessary slices.

Working in Python 2.x.

Comment: I'd propose to reframe the question to focus purely on how to store a slice expression. +1 either way

Comment: You can use a tuple of  `slice` to make it work with multiple dimentions

Comment: You could use lambdas and pass the array

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The syntax `[:, :2, :, :540]` is turned into a tuple of `slice` objects by Python:

```
(slice(None, None, None),
 slice(None, 2, None),
 slice(None, None, None),
 slice(None, 540, None))
```

A convenient way to generate this tuple is to use the special function* [`np.s_`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.s_.html). You just need to pass it the `[...]` expression. For example:

```
>>> np.s_[:540]
slice(None, 540, None)
>>> np.s_[:, :2, :, :540]
(slice(None, None, None),
 slice(None, 2, None),
 slice(None, None, None),
 slice(None, 540, None))
```

Then your dictionary of slices could be written as:

```
lookup = {0: np.s_[:540],
          30: np.s_[540:1080],
          60: np.s_[1080:]}
```

* *technically `s_` is an alias for the class [`IndexExpression`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/index_tricks.py#l603) that implements a special `__getitem__` method.*

Comment: I did not know about `np.s_`, absolutely awesome as it allows for more readability for someone not as comfortable with pure python slice notation.

Comment: I was about to suggest writing a custom class with a simple `def __getitem__(self, item): return item`, but that I guess that is basically what `s_` does. Didn't know about that one!

Answer (score 2):

Numpy has a lot of [Indexing routines](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.indexing.html) .And  in this case you can use the following functions for Generating index arrays :

`c_`    : Translates slice objects to concatenation along the second axis.

`r_`    : Translates slice objects to concatenation along the first axis.

`s_`    : **A nicer way to build up index tuples for arrays**.

You can also use [`numpy.unravel_index`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html#numpy.unravel_index) :

> Converts a tuple of index arrays into an array of flat indices, applying boundary modes to the multi-index.