# Slicing NumPy array with dictionary

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, slice

Is there a simple option to slice a NumPy array with the predefined dictionary of indices?

For example:

```
>> a = array([3, 9, 1, 5, 5])
```

and (fictitious) dictionary:

```
>> index_dict = {'all_except_first': (1:None), 'all_except_last': (None:-1)}
```

and then:

```
>> a[index_dict['all_except_first']]
>> array([9, 1, 5, 5])
>> a[index_dict['all_except_first']]
>> array([3, 9, 1, 5])
```

Sort of slicing with names and not with numbers.

Comment: You could create slices: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice

Comment: @IljaEverilä, thanks! While I was reading how to implement it, Uriel Eli did an amazing job. thank you guys!

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30244731/numpy-slice-notation-in-a-dictionary/30244830

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice)s:

```
>>> index_dict = {'all_except_first': slice(1, None), 'all_except_last': slice(None, -1)}
>>>
>>> a[index_dict['all_except_first']]
array([9, 1, 5, 5])
>>> a[index_dict['all_except_last']]
array([3, 9, 1, 5])
```

Comment: I felt I was close :) Many thanks for your solution!!